# Is it possible to upgrade LiveOS by replacing /BOOT directory?

Tags: linux, upgrade

I make a live.iso by [livemedia-creator](https://weldr.io/lorax/livemedia-creator.html) and installed it to disk by [livecd-tools](https://github.com/livecd-tools/livecd-tools/blob/main/tools/livecd-iso-to-disk.sh). I want to update this system with another live.iso.

What I have tried is: copy the squashfs.img, paste to the overlayfs directory of current running system. The copying can success. But after copying, every command reports `segmentation fault`. I have to turn off the power and reboot computer.

Is it possible to upgrade a liveOS by replacing the kernel files?

I looked up some OTA framework. They are too complicated. If anyone could give me some advice or direction? Thanks very much~~~

Comment: The general answer is yes, but you have to start from the beginning and create a new iso file and check that everything is compatible. I am not sure that I understand what you describe, but you won't succeed with the kind of shortcut that I *think* you are trying.

Comment: You are right. My attempt is failed. My basic idea is the whole system is running in RAM, so I replace the `/boot` directory with updated one should be fine. But the truth is I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found 2 solutions:

1. Editing grub.cfg, adding a new entry to boot a `ota.iso`. After reboot, you should boot into the `ota.iso`, then update ota.iso to the target boot disk by `livecd-tools`.
2. Replace `squashfs.img` with updated one. Reboot and the rootfs is updated.

From my test results, they works. Hope to be helpful.